# How to handle complex form with React

Tags: reactjs, redux

What is the React way of handling a complex form (with or without redux)? I would like to port an application that has a form/document with nested data model and finding it hard to find an example.

Simplified data model:

```
var model = {
    name: {
        first: 'Firstname',
        last: 'Lastname'
    },
    age: 25,
    hobbies: [{
        name: 'fising',
        medals: [{
            name: 'Gold medal',
            year: 2000
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'sleeping',
        medals: [{
            name: 'Gold medal',
            year: 2000
        }, {
            name: 'Gold medal',
            year: 2014
        }]
    }],
    education: [{
        school: 'School 1',
        year: 2000
    }, {
        school: 'School 2',
        year: 2010
    }]
}
```

Example using angularjs - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/30964/

Comment: There is `redux-form` and an alternative `react-redux-form` that I had a good experience with. They tie every form of any complexity to a model such as the one you pasted and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 4):

## Multiple Form Handler

You can create your own form handler creating a component that includes a input receiving some props... and checking if it changes with `onChange` that will call an `action creator` that dispatch an `action` that change the `state`. You can create on the `state` a property with the name of the form and with the properties of the inputs.

Here is my example using React-bootstrap and Next.js:

#### Input Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { inputChange } from '../actions';

class Input extends Component {
  inputChange = (title, name, e) => {
    this.props.inputChange(title, name, e.target.value)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText">
          <ControlLabel>{this.props.controlLabel}</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            disabled={this.props.disabled}
            type={this.props.type || 'Text'}
            placeholder={this.props.controlLabel}
            onChange={(e) => this.inputChange(this.props.title, this.props.name, e)}
            value={this.props.val}
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    inputChange: bindActionCreators(inputChange, dispatch)
  }
}
```

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Input);
    export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Input);
You can use this component many times as you can, the most important thing is to pass the `props`: `title`, `name` and `placeholder`. The `title` is going to be the name of the form, and the `name`is going to be the name of the input.

#### Action Creator

```
export const inputChange = (title, name, val) => dispatch => {
  return dispatch ({ type: INPUT_VALUE, title, name, val})
};
```

Every time the input has any change it will call this action.

#### Form Reducer

```
export default (state = {}, action ) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INPUT_VALUE': 
      return { ...state, 
        [action.title]: 
          { ...state[action.title],  
            [action.name]: action.val 
          }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

### E.g

```
import { Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';

import Input from '../handlers/Input';

const UserForm = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col lg={8} lgOffset={4}>
            <Input controlLabel="Name" title="user" name="name" />
          </Col>
          <Col lg={8} lgOffset={4}>
            <Input controlLabel="Last name" title="user" name="lastName" />
          </Col>
          <Col lg={8} lgOffset={4}>
            <Input controlLabel="Email" type="email" title="user" name="email" />
          </Col>
          <Col lg={8} lgOffset={4}>
            <Input controlLabel="Password" type="password" title="user" name="password" />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
}

export default UserForm;
```

### Output

```
{
  "formReducer": {
    "user": {
      "name": "Jhon",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "jhondoe@test.com",
      "password": "Password123"
    }
  }
}
```

#### [Demo](https://redux-form-bugjunbzww.now.sh/)

#### [Full repo](https://github.com/estrada9166/form-handler)

Answer (score 1):

With redux, there's `redux-form`.

Without redux I'd create a form that handles field changes, display their values and warn for possible validations.

Additionally, create another component or container that handlers those validations and changes and later propagate them back to your component.

Consider this example as big picture of something you might need and use.

```
const YourModelForm = ({ model, onChange }) => 
  <div>
    <input type="text" value={model.name.first} onChange={({ target }) => onChange('name.first', target.value)} />
    <input type="text" value={model.name.last} onChange={({ target }) => onChange('name.last', target.value)} />

    <input type="number" value={model.age} onChange={({ target }) => onChange('age', target.value)} />

    ...

    /*
     Here you can create custom components for each property that model has.
     Maybe a nice input text, dropdown, number fields and such.
     Remember to always keep them dumb for future reuses.
    */
  </div>

class YourModelContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.onModelChange = this.onModelChange.bind(this)
  }

  onModelChange(prop, newValue) {
    /*
    Update your model here. 
    - Dispatch a redux action, update your state as you wish
    */
  }

  render() {
    // Let's assume you've got your model as props. It also works from state as well
    const { model, onChange } = this.props

    return(
      <div>
        ...

        <YourModelForm model={model} onChange={onModelChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```